# Textbook error or my own error, Law of sines question.

Tags: trigonometry, education

A triangle with side 8 inches and corresponding angle 13 degrees, side x inches and corresponding angle 120 degrees.

To answer this I set up a proportion:

$\sin \left(13\right)/8=\sin \left(120\right)/x$

$x\sin \left(13\right)=8\sin \left(120\right)$

$x=8\sin \left(120\right)/\sin \left(13\right)$

$x=30.8$

The information from the triangle is right, but the answer is not listed, as it should be. Have I done something wrong mathematically or is the book wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting up your triangle as follows, then you're correct.

[image]

Comment: Yes, That's how I set it up.